# UIScrollView with UITableView not scrollable

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

My App (Xamarin/monotouch for iPhone) consists of three UITableView which I add to a UIScrollView (all is done programtically)
Each of the tables is not scrollable

```
myTableView.ScrollEnabled = false;
```

I calculate the height needed for x number of items and set it in runtime.

```
myTableView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 27, 320, myTableViewHeight);
```

The problem is that the UIScrollView is not scrollable:

```
int caclulateScrollViewHeight = myListHeight + oListHeight + 104;
scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (320, caclulateScrollViewHeight);
scrollView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 135, 320, caclulateScrollViewHeight);


scrollView.DelaysContentTouches = true;
scrollView.CanCancelContentTouches = false;
this.View.Add (scrollView);
```

Any idea what can cause that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set your scrollView frame height the same as your calculated view height. The frame is the box on screen that you want it to occupy; generally you'll want to keep this less than or equal to screen size. If your content size matches your frame size, it won't scroll (because it won't need to).

```
scrollView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 135, 320, 200);
```